# How to rezise all panels within a winform without overlap

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with panels. I want all the panels to be resized when the form resizes but without overlap between them. Like this

[image: Panels resizing]

I have tried to put this anchors on the panels: **Top, Bottom, Left, Right**.  But the result is like this

[image]

Obviously this is wrong. So, is there some way to configure the panel properties in order to behave like I propose?

Comment: Use `TableLayoutPanel` and set column size type to percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon @Reza's comment, what you want to do is place a [TableLayoutPanel Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492143.aspx) on the form.  This control will either be anchored on all sides (top, bottom, left, and right) or set to `Dock` = `Fill`.  You would want to add four columns to the `TableLayoutPanel` and tweak the sizing options (e.g. setting each column width to 25%).  Then you would place your panels in the different cells of the TableLayoutPanel.  This should give you the sizing behavior that you would like.